# Having a gaming computer makes my cousin get hooked on playing games. - is me or my cousin who has the computer?

Tags: meaning, gerunds

**Example 1**

> Having a gaming computer makes my cousin get hooked on playing games.

This means my cousin has a gaming computer and that makes my cousin get hooked on playing video games.

**Example 2**

> Having a gaming computer makes my cousin come to my house and play video games.

This implies that it is me that has the computer. But doesn't this mean Example 1 can have a different meaning as well? It can mean "(Me) having a gaming computer makes my cousin get hooked on playing games."

So, when the subject of gerund is omitted, how do we interpret it?

Comment: I would never read either of these as "**I** have a computer, therefore...", and I don't think that #2 does imply that it's me who has the computer.  In general, you can't omit the subject of the gerund/participle/modifier without risking severe confusion about who or what it applies to.

Comment: To **make someone do/get something** sounds like your cousin had no choice in the matter, or that he was forced to do something against his will. I think you should probably consider changing the construction, unless you actually mean that.

Answer (score 2):

When a passive gerund is used in English, its subject is determined by context.

In other words, in your sentence, the grammar does not determine who owns the computer - the listener must fill in this information from context.

Compare:

"**I own a computer.  Having it is making my cousin get hooked on video games.**"

"**My cousin's family owns a computer.  Having it is making my cousin get hooked on video games.**"

Notice that the implied subject of the verb in the second sentence is different in each example ("I", "My cousin's family"), but the words in the second sentence are unchanged.  So, it is up to the listener to determine the subject from context.

Without any prior context, the implied subject can default to the object of a related clause, as in your example, or to the speaker, as in the example:

"**Having a computer is really making work easier!**"

In this last example, without any context, we assume that the speaker owns the computer in question.  However, a little bit of context in a previous sentence can change this:

"**I consult with a small accounting firm, and recently updated their office.  Having a computer is really making work easier!**"

Comment: I just made a small "non-edit" so I could cancel my original upvote. I *don't* think your final example is convincing. It's true that the nearest noun phrase to the "dangling" gerund ***having*** is in fact ***their office***, but we normally look *forwards* rather than backwards. This is a slightly unusual context because there's ***no*** credible referent later in the same sentence - so I have to go back to the preceding sentence as a whole, and start reading it from the beginning. And the first word ***is*** the subject there, so it's natural for me to link the *next* sentence back to that.

Comment: ...So I just end up thinking your final example is badly phrased, and that second sentence should start with ***Them** having a computer...*

Comment: None of what you wrote above makes any sense. "nearest noun phrase", "looking forwards", "credible referent", etc, etc.   You're making up terms, none of that is real or is explained in a comprehensible way.   This is overthinking in a grossly idiosyncratic way; you are confusing both yourself and others that might read your comment.

I am a native speaker, and after your comment vetted each of my examples with native speakers of SAE, AAVE, RP, and MLE who have studied English grammar formally.  All understand the sentence and agree that "having" tags "small accounting firm" as the subject.

Comment: Further:  "Them having a computer is really making work easier is really making work easier" is terrible diction, you'd be marked down in a college course.  Instead, say: "Having a computer is really making their work easier."

Simply google for the general principle if you do not understand the language well enough to intuitively grasp its truth - "the subject of a passive gerund is determined by context" is a basic grammar rule and you'll find many more examples in a textbook or online.

Comment: @Balzen: You're starting to feel like a troll to me. Ease off, willya?

Comment: Please stay topical / relevant.  I am not "trolling" but responding to your comment, which is honestly fairly wild, that comment is not helpful.  That said - if I see false, unverifiable, or plain wrong information on ELL, or grammar examples that are confusing or not natural use, I will call those out every time.   I don't look at or consider who wrote them, so if you feel like you are getting that a lot from me or people in general - that's probably not some kind of statistical error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "grammar" (the actual words, rather than the *meaning*) normally *does* resolve any ambiguity in such contexts. Consider...

> 1: *Having a smartphone means **I contact my brother** more often*
> 2: *Having a smartphone means **my brother contacts me** more often*

I believe the default readings there are that in #1 it's ***me*** who has the smartphone that makes the difference (it's contextually irrelevant whether my brother's phone is a smartphone, "dumb" mobile phone, or a landline phone). But in #2 the default reading is I'm talking about ***my brother's*** smartphone.

That's to say, as in many other contexts where the referent of some text element is ambiguous, the *default* parsing should normally be ***the nearest credible<sup>1</sup> referent*** (in my examples, ***I*** or ***my brother***).

---

<sup>1</sup> When I use ***credible*** in such contexts, I mean *the nearest referent **that makes sense*** (it may not *actually* be the right choice, but it's "believable" that it *could* be).

The OP thinks his second version "makes more sense" if we assume it's the *speaker* who has the gaming PC, but I agree with @stangdon's comment that *both* versions imply it's the brother's machine (because in both cases the *only* credible noun phrase actually present is ***my brother***).

Comment: To a native / fluent English speaker, your `#1` is correct, and your `#2` is not - the second example is ambiguous.  Neither of these contradicts the principle that context determines the subject of a gerund in passive voice, you simply provide context in both sentences here (and it is insufficient to determine your meaning in the second - a native speaker would need to ask you if it were an important distinction.)